# Pandas - Cumulative Count with Labeling

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas df that looks like the following:

```
+---------+---------+------------+--------+
| Cluster | Country | Publishers | Assets |
+---------+---------+------------+--------+
| South   | IT      | SS         | Asset1 |
| South   | IT      | SS         | Asset2 |
| South   | IT      | SS         | Asset3 |
| South   | IT      | ML         | Asset1 |
| South   | IT      | ML         | Asset2 |
| South   | IT      | ML         | Asset3 |
| South   | IT      | TT         | Asset1 |
| South   | IT      | TT         | Asset2 |
| South   | IT      | TT         | Asset3 |
| South   | ES      | SS         | Asset1 |
| South   | ES      | SS         | Asset2 |
+---------+---------+------------+--------+
```

I would like to create a new column "Package" that uses a cumulative count based on the following columns:

- Publishers
- Assets

The result would be this:

```
+---------+---------+------------+--------+---------+
| Cluster | Country | Publishers | Assets | Package |
+---------+---------+------------+--------+---------+
| South   | IT      | SS         | Asset1 | 1       |
| South   | IT      | SS         | Asset2 | 1a      |
| South   | IT      | SS         | Asset3 | 1b      |
| South   | IT      | ML         | Asset1 | 2       |
| South   | IT      | ML         | Asset2 | 2a      |
| South   | IT      | ML         | Asset3 | 2b      |
| South   | IT      | TT         | Asset1 | 3       |
| South   | IT      | TT         | Asset2 | 3a      |
| South   | IT      | TT         | Asset3 | 3b      |
| South   | ES      | SS         | Asset1 | 4       |
| South   | ES      | SS         | Asset2 | 4a      |
+---------+---------+------------+--------+---------+
```

So far I have tried

df['Package'] = df.groupby(['Cluster','Publishers']).cumcount() but it seems not to work as the value resets to 0 after every publisher instance is gone through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), but with a different grouper. You will also need the related [`groupby.ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html):

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

# group by consecutive identical values
group = df['Publishers'].ne(df['Publishers'].shift()).cumsum()
# alternatively, you can also group by Cluster/Country/Publishers
# group = ['Cluster', 'Country', 'Publisher']


df['Package'] =(
  df.groupby(group).ngroup().add(1).astype(str)
 +df.groupby(group).cumcount().map(dict(enumerate(['']+list(ascii_lowercase))))
)
```

output:

```
   Cluster Country Publishers  Assets Package
0    South      IT         SS  Asset1       1
1    South      IT         SS  Asset2      1a
2    South      IT         SS  Asset3      1b
3    South      IT         ML  Asset1       2
4    South      IT         ML  Asset2      2a
5    South      IT         ML  Asset3      2b
6    South      IT         TT  Asset1       3
7    South      IT         TT  Asset2      3a
8    South      IT         TT  Asset3      3b
9    South      ES         SS  Asset1       4
10   South      ES         SS  Asset2      4a
```

Comment: This is amazing. If I had a column 'Budget' that has the same value across 1, 1a, 1b, is there a way to keep only the value for those lines that are 1,2,3,4 and not 1a, 1b or 2a, 2b, etc?

Comment: @MattM you should probably open a new question (or edit this one if the request is minor), it's much easier to understand with a clear, well formatted, example ;)

Comment: Agreed, apologies. @Mozway!